# Блокировка поля при нажатии на radiobutton

Tags: javascript, html

Необходимо при нажатии на определенный radiobutton блокировать некоторые поля.

```
function agreeForm() {
if (#autoVK.checked){
    #countryVK.disabled = 1;

}
if(#settingsVK.checked){
  #countryVK.disabled = 0;

}
```

Вот такой код почему-то не работает. 
Сами поля

```
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input name="typeVK" id="autoVK" value="1" checked="" type="radio" onclick="agreeForm();">Автоматический
</label>

<label class="radio-inline">
    <input name="typeVK" id="settingsVK" value="0" type="radio" onclick="agreeForm();">С параметрами
</label>

<input id="countryVK" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Страна" style="width:120px">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С использованием **jquery**:

```js
$("#countryVK").attr("disabled","disabled");

$(".control").change(function(){
  if($(this).val()=="1"){
    $("#countryVK").attr("disabled","disabled").val('');
  }else{
    $("#countryVK").removeAttr("disabled");
  }   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input name="type" id="autoVK" value="1" class="control" checked="" type="radio">
  Автоматический
</label>

<label class="radio-inline">
    <input name="type" id="settingsVK" value="0" type="radio" class="control" >С параметрами
</label>

<input id="countryVK" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Страна" style="width:120px">
```